# TM1 user access to element level dimension

Tags: cognos-tm1

USer 1 needs access to this combination – Function “1C0” only – Period “Bud 2019” – Version “ Budget1”

User 2 needs access to this combination - Functions “1B0”, “1D0” and “1C1” only – Period “Bud 2019” – Version “Budget1”

function, period and version are dimension

1CO,1BO and 1C1 are elements of function dimensions
Bud 2019 is element of Period dimensions
"Budget1" is element of version dimension

how to provide write access for users for this element in above dimension, how to achieve this tm1 and to test as well

Thanks,
Sathya

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set Read/Write rights in `}CellSecurity_<cubename>` cube for that cube setting. Have you tried that?
You can define cell security very precisely there from these cubes.